# Find the proper mathematical description of the minimum positive value.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $S \triangleq \{ 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.8, 1, ...\}$. I want to know the proper mathematical description of the minimum positive value. Is it $\min \{S>0\}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\min_{s\in S,s>0}s$$ or $$\min\{s\in S, s>0:s\}.$$

You might also abbreviate as

$$\min S_{>0}.$$